# Excel vba macro intermittently fails to send data from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that open a closed workbook

sends data to this workbook, saves, then closes

sometimes it fails to send some of the data, or All of the data.
But doesn't throw ant error messages.

```
Public Sub PushUpdate315_CLIP()

If Range("H49").Value = "QCS UPLOADED" Then
MsgBox ("QCS had already been uploaded, if you believe this is an error, Please see Supervisor")
Exit Sub
End If

If Range("G54").Value = "" Then

Dim coreTime As Long
Dim lidTime As Long
Dim caseTime As Long
Dim finalTime As Long


coreValue = Range("L13").Value
lidValue = Range("L19").Value
caseValue = Range("L23").Value
finalValue = Range("L44").Value

If coreValue <= 0.0034722 Then
MsgBox ("Core Time is NOT Valid")
Exit Sub
End If

If lidValue <= 1.04166666666667E-02 Then
MsgBox ("Lid Time is NOT Valid")
Exit Sub
End If

If caseValue <= 0.002777778 Then
MsgBox ("Case Time is NOT Valid")
Exit Sub
End If

If finalValue <= 0.006944444 Then
MsgBox ("Final Time is NOT Valid")
Exit Sub
End If

End If


'315 Push update
    Dim serverFileName As String 'obtain url for sharepoint filename, insert below
    Dim x As New Excel.Application 'make a new session for the sharepoint version
    Dim w As Workbook 'grab-handle for the sharepoint file
    x.Visible = True
    x.ScreenUpdating = True
    serverFileName = "SUPERSECRETLINK HERE/Module Impedances.xlsx"
   
    Set w = x.Workbooks.Open(serverFileName) 'open the sharepoint version
    
    w.Save
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
    
    
    If sheetExists(Range("B6").Text, w) Then
    
    
    'w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("A2").Value = "test"
    lastrow = w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("A" & lastrow).Value = Range("B5").Text  ' WO
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("B" & lastrow).Value = Range("B7").Text  ' Serial
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("D" & lastrow).Value = Range("D11").Text ' Core Imp
    'w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("E" & lastrow).Value = Range("D28").Text ' Take Off Imp
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("F" & lastrow).Value = Range("D26").Text ' Term Imp
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("G" & lastrow).Value = Range("H13").Text ' Core Time
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("H" & lastrow).Value = Range("H19").Text ' Case Time (lid)
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("I" & lastrow).Value = Range("H23").Text ' mini bms (Sink Core)
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("J" & lastrow).Value = Range("H44").Text 'cabling time (finsihing)
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("K" & lastrow).Value = Range("H45").Text ' balance time
    'w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("L" & lastrow).Value = Range("H36").Text ' testing
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("M" & lastrow).Value = Range("I47").Text ' total labor
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("N" & lastrow).Value = Range("I49").Text ' total labor with waiting
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("O" & lastrow).Value = Range("I49").Text ' total lead time
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("P" & lastrow).Value = (Range("H13").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("P" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("Q" & lastrow).Value = (Range("H19").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("Q" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("R" & lastrow).Value = (Range("H23").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("R" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("S" & lastrow).Value = (Range("H44").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("S" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("T" & lastrow).Value = (Range("H45").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("T" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("V" & lastrow).Value = (Range("I47").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("V" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("W" & lastrow).Value = (Range("I49").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("W" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("X" & lastrow).Value = (Range("I49").Value) * 1440
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("X" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General"
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("Y" & lastrow).Value = MonthName(Month(Range("G44").Text), True)
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("Z" & lastrow).Value = Year(Range("G44").Text)
    
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("AA" & lastrow).Value = MonthName(Month(Range("G44").Text), True) + CStr(Year(Range("G44").Text))
      
     w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("AG" & lastrow).Value = Range("G44").Text
      
    w.Save
    w.Close
    x.Quit
    
    
    MsgBox ("Data sent to Metrics")
    Range("H49").Value = "QCS UPLOADED"
    
    BuildUnit
     
    Else
    MsgBox ("This Battery Type does not exists yet in the databse, Please contact QCS Site data admin")
    End If
 On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks("Macros.xlsm").Close
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Its really strange how some values get sent and others dont.

for example:

```
w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("F" & lastrow).Value = Range("D26").Text ' Term Imp
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("G" & lastrow).Value = Range("H13").Text ' Core Time
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("H" & lastrow).Value = Range("H19").Text ' Case Time (lid)
    w.Sheets(Range("B6").Text).Range("I" & lastrow).Value = Range("H23").Text ' mini bms (Sink Core)
```

I've literally seen where the first and last value get sent but not the ones the middle?

Comment: I doubt any of us can tell based on the information provided. You should specify a sheet (and workbook) where you refer to `Range("B6").Text`. And why are you using Text property?

Comment: `Dim x As New Excel.Application`  there's no need to create a new instance of Excel to open the other workbook - you can just use `Workbooks.Open()` in the current instance to do that.

Comment: Have you actually stepped though your code and seen this behavior "live", or is this based on examining the sheet you're copying to and noticing "gaps" ?  Might be worth adding a check for a missing WO in B5 before copying, otherwise you run the risk of overwriting that line on the next copy...